# Indy doesn't get response text returned with error 404

Tags: httpresponse, indy, http-error, delphi-10-seattle

My HTTP server returns custom 404 error text when REST route is not found:

```
{"sessionIdent":"051F-dUen7-tetW-kNf82-WxT","Details":[{"messageCode":60,"messageCategory":"","messageText":"No matching route for \"POST \/Warehouse\/A1\/Orders\/execute\""}]}
```

Following JavaScript code displays this response text in browser just fine:

```js
function httpReq(method, url, headers, jsonStr, userName, password) {
    try
    {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open(method, url, true);

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            console.log("onreadystatechange");
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                console.log("ready");
                console.log(xmlhttp.status);
                console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        }
        // Send the request
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, max-age=0');
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Session-Ident', '051F-dUen7-tetW-kNf82-WxT');
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
        if (headers) {
            var headerKeys = Object.keys(headers);
            Object.keys(headers).forEach(key => {
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader(key, headers[key]);
            });
        }
        if ((userName !== "") && (password !== ""))
        {
          xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(userName + ":" + password));
        }
        console.log("before send");
        xmlhttp.send(jsonStr);
        console.log("after send");
    }
    catch (ex)
    {
        console.log(ex);
    }
}
```

Indy's `TIdHTTP` raises an `EIdHTTPProtocolException` exception with message `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found` instead of my response text inside.

When I use the `hoNoProtocolErrorException` option:

```
_client.HTTPOptions := _client.HTTPOptions + [hoNoProtocolErrorException];
```

exception is not raised any more, but response text is empty.

```pascal
procedure TFormRestTest._httpSend(AMethod, APath, AHeaders, ABody: string);
var
  queryData, replyData: TStream;
  resultText: string;
begin
  queryData := TStringStream.Create(ABody, TEncoding.UTF8);
  try
    replyData := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      _client.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
      _client.Request.CharSet := 'UTF-8';
      _client.Request.BasicAuthentication := True;
      _client.Request.Username := 'Username';
      _client.Request.Password := 'Password';
      _client.Request.CustomHeaders.Clear;
      _client.Request.CustomHeaders.Text := AHeaders;
      _client.DoRequest(AMethod, APath, queryData, replyData, []);
      replyData.Position := 0;
      resultText = ReadStringAsCharset(replyData, _client.Response.CharSet)]);
      _log(resultText);  //resultText is empty
    finally
      replyData.Free();
    end;
  finally
    queryData.Free();
  end;
end;
```

How can I retrieve my response body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I use the `hoNoProtocolErrorException` option ... exception is not raised any more, but response text is empty.

That is by design.  When disabling the exception, you need to *also* enable the `hoWantProtocolErrorContent` option to actually receive the response's body data into your `replyData` stream, eg:

```
_client.HTTPOptions := _client.HTTPOptions + [hoNoProtocolErrorException, hoWantProtocolErrorContent];
```

This is explained in more detail on the following article on [Indy's Changelog Blog](https://www.indyproject.org/blog/):

[New TIdHTTP flags and OnChunkReceived event](https://www.indyproject.org/2016/01/10/new-tidhttp-flags-and-onchunkreceived-event/)

> Three new flag have been added to the `TIdHTTP.HTTPOptions` property:
>
> ...
>
> - **hoWantProtocolErrorContent**: when an HTTP error response is received, `TIdHTTP` normally reads and discards the response’s message body and then raises `EIdHTTPProtocolException` (the message body is available in the `EIdHTTPProtocolException.ErrorMessage` property). If the `hoNoProtocolErrorException` flag is enabled, or the `ResponseCode` number is specified in the request’s `AIgnoreReplies` parameter, then no `EIdHTTPProtocolException` is raised, as the caller would like to process the `ResponseCode` manually. **Normally `TIdHTTP` would still discard the message body, though. If this new flag is enabled, the message body will no longer be discarded**, it will be saved in the caller’s target `TStream` like a successful response would be. This flag is disabled by default to preserve existing behavior to discard error message bodies.
>
> ...

Based on your [earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49016689/idhttp-post-cant-read-response-text/49017375?noredirect=1#comment131160709_54446375) to another question, you seem to not have the `hoWantProtocolErrorContent` option available in your version of Indy. In which case, you are using a very outdated version of Indy and should upgrade to the latest version from [Indy's GitHub repository](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/).

**UPDATE:** If that is not an option for you, for whatever reason, then you have no choice but to catch the `EIdHTTPProtocolException` and read the body content from its `ErrorMessage` property, eg:

```pascal
try
  _client.DoRequest(AMethod, APath, queryData, replyData, []);
  replyData.Position := 0;
  resultText := ReadStringAsCharset(replyData, _client.Response.CharSet)]);
except
  on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
    resultText := E.ErrorMessage;
end;
```

Comment: Remy, thank you for your reply. Unfortunately at my work and I do not decide whether to update components or not. So I have to put up with versions that were installed by VM creators in our company. Otherwise I can include components directly in the project if it is possible. Are there ways to retrieve response text with old version of Indy?

Comment: Of course, I would use any opportunity. Your answer shows that I mixed up `e.Message` and `e.ErrorMessage`. Everything is working now!